# Ampscript Loop : Multiple rows needed in multi-column email layout

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, gtl

My newsletter was set up to loop per row in the DE to fill in needed info into a content block that gets created up to 35 times. There has been a new content block that now requires I pull two or more row information per loop. I was thinking about using the mod() function but each column per row duplicates. Sort of long but below you will see what I currently have in place.

```
%%[ set @artistCount = 0 ]%%

{{.datasource JSONArtists type=nested maxrows = 35}}
{{.data}}
{ "target" : "JSONVar.artists" }
{{/data}}
%%[
SET @artistId = TreatAsContent('{{artistId}}')
SET @eventBorderTopFlag = 1
SET @artistLookup = LookupOrderedRowsCS('ENT.edb_event_artists', 1, 'artist_Id asc', 'artist_Id', @artistId)
SET @isExcluded = ''
SET @isExcluded = Lookup('Exclusion', 'artist_id', 'artist_id', @artistId)

IF ROWCOUNT(@artistLookup) > 0 AND Empty(@isExcluded) THEN
SET @artistInfo = Row(@artistLookup, 1)
SET @artistID = Field(@artistInfo, 'artist_id')
SET @artistEventCount = 0
SET @eventDates = ''
]%%

{{.datasource JSONEvents type=nested }}
{{.data}}
{ "target" : "JSONArtists.events" }
{{/data}}
%%[
SET @artistEventCount = ADD(@artistEventCount, 1)

SET @eventId = TreatAsContent('{{eventId}}')

IF Length(@eventId) <= 15 THEN
SET @eventId = concat('0', @eventId)
ENDIF

IF @artistEventCount == 1 THEN
SET @eventDE = LookupOrderedRowsCS('ENT.edb_events', 1, 'event_ID asc', 'event_ID', @eventId)
IF RowCount(@eventDE) >= 1 THEN
SET @eventRow = Row(@eventDE, 1)
SET @venue_name = Field(@eventRow, 'venue_name')
SET @eventDates = Concat('<span style="font-weight:bold">', Format(Field(@eventRow, 'event_date'), 'ddd, MMM d'), "</span> at ", @venue_name, "<br />")
ENDIF
ENDIF

IF @artistEventCount > 1 AND @artistEventCount < 5 THEN
SET @eventDE = LookupOrderedRowsCS('ENT.edb_events', 1, 'event_ID asc', 'event_ID', @eventId)
IF RowCount(@eventDE) >= 1 THEN
SET @eventRow = Row(@eventDE, 1)
SET @venue_name = Field(@eventRow, 'venue_name')
SET @eventDates = Concat(@eventDates, '<span style="font-weight:bold">', Format(Field(@eventRow, 'event_date'), 'ddd, MMM d'), "</span> at ", @venue_name, "<br />")
ENDIF
ENDIF
]%%
{{/datasource}}

{{.datasource JSONEvents type=nested  maxrows = 1}}
{{.data}}
{ "target" : "JSONArtists.events" }
{{/data}}
%%[
SET @eventId = TreatAsContent('{{eventId}}')
SET @eventLookup = LookupOrderedRowsCS('ENT.edb_events', 1, 'event_ID asc', 'event_ID', @eventId)
SET @isExcluded = ''
SET @isExcluded = lookup('Exclusion', 'event_id', 'event_id', @eventId)

IF ROWCOUNT(@eventLookup) > 0 AND Empty(@isExcluded) THEN

SET @BASE_URL = "http://concerts..com"
SET @IMAGE_URL = "http://media..com/tm/en-us/"
SET @eventTemp = Row(@eventLookup, 1)

IF @artistEventCount == 1 THEN
SET @eventDates = ''
SET @ymal_event_id = Field(@eventTemp, 'event_id')
SET @ymal_event_date = Field(@eventTemp, 'event_date')
SET @ymal_event_time = Field(@eventTemp, 'event_time')
SET @ymal_artist_id = Field(@eventTemp, 'primary_artist_id')
SET @ymal_artist_name = Field(@eventTemp, 'primary_artist_name')
SET @ymal_venue_id = Field(@eventTemp, 'venue_id')
SET @ymal_venue_name = Field(@eventTemp, 'venue_name')
SET @onsale_on = Field(@eventTemp, 'onsale_date')
SET @onsale_off = Field(@eventTemp, 'onsale_date_end')
SET @presale_on = Field(@eventTemp, 'presale_date')
SET @presale_off = Field(@eventTemp, 'presale_date_end')
SET @ymal_event_url = "http://media..com/tmimages/305x225_music.jpg"

SET @venue_addr = ''

IF Field(@eventTemp, 'system_url') != '' And Field(@eventTemp, 'system_url') != 'undefined' THEN
SET @ymal_event_url = Field(@eventTemp, 'system_url')
ELSE
SET @ymal_event_url = Concat(@BASE_URL,'/event/',@ymal_event_id)
ENDIF
ELSE
SET @ymal_event_id = Field(@eventTemp, 'event_id')
SET @ymal_event_date = ''
SET @ymal_event_time = ''
SET @ymal_artist_id = Field(@eventTemp, 'primary_artist_id')
SET @ymal_artist_name = Field(@eventTemp, 'primary_artist_name')
SET @ymal_venue_id = ''
SET @ymal_venue_name = ''
SET @onsale_on = ''
SET @onsale_off = ''
SET @presale_on = ''
SET @presale_off = ''
SET @ymal_event_url = ''
SET @venue_addr = ''
ENDIF

SET @ymal_imgSrc = ""
SET @imageLookup = LookupOrderedRowsCS('ENT.edb_artist_images', 1, 'tmol_modified desc', 'event_id', @ymal_event_id,'artist_ID',@ymal_artist_id,'image_width',305)

IF ROWCOUNT(@imageLookup) > 0 THEN
SET @imageRows = Row(@imageLookup, 1)
SET @ymal_imgSrc = Concat(@IMAGE_URL,Field(@imageRows, 'image_name'))
ELSE
SET @eventArtistsLookup2 = LookupRows('ENT.edb_event_artists','event_id', @ymal_event_id)
IF ROWCOUNT(@eventArtistsLookup2) > 0 THEN
FOR @i = 1 to RowCount(@eventArtistsLookup2) DO

SET @eventArtistsLookup2Rows = Row(@eventArtistsLookup2, @i)
SET @subAID = Field(@eventArtistsLookup2Rows, 'artist_id')
SET @rank =0
SET @rank =  Field(@eventArtistsLookup2Rows, 'rank')

IF @subAID != @ymal_artist_id AND (@rank == 127 OR @rank == 1) THEN

SET @imageResults2 = LookupOrderedRowsCS('ENT.edb_artist_images', 1, 'tmol_modified desc', 'event_id', @ymal_event_id,'artist_ID',@subAID ,'image_width',305)
IF ROWCOUNT(@imageResults2) > 0 THEN

SET @eventArtistsLookup2Rows = Row(@imageResults2, 1)
SET @ymal_imgSrc = Concat(@IMAGE_URL,Field(@eventArtistsLookup2Rows, 'image_name'))
SET @imgWidth = Field(@eventArtistsLookup2Rows, 'image_width')
ENDIF
ENDIF
NEXT @i
ENDIF
ENDIF

SET @ymal_imgSrc = Iif(Empty(@ymal_imgSrc), "http://media..com/tmimages/305x225_music.jpg", @ymal_imgSrc)

IF @artistEventCount > 1 THEN
SET @ymal_event_url = Concat("http://www..com/artist/", @ymal_artist_id)
ENDIF

IF @artistCount <= 19 THEN
SET @a5Alias =  Concat("event ",@artistCount)
SET @a5Extra = "&nbsp;"
IF @artistEventCount > 1 THEN
SET @a5Extra = Concat('<span valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans serif; color:#333333; font-size:18px; line-height:21px;font-weight:400;padding:15px 0 0 0" class="opensans centerText text18px">', @eventDates ,'</span><br>')
ENDIF
IF @artistEventCount > 1 THEN
SET @a5Extra = Concat(@a5Extra, '<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#e41937; text-transform:uppercase;" href="', @ymal_event_url, '" alias="event', @artistCount,'">See More Dates</a>')
ENDIF
]%%
%%=ContentAreaByName("Shared Items\Shared Contents\DevModule\NewsletterA5Dev")=%%
%%[ ELSE
SET @b3Alias =  Concat("event ",@artistCount);
SET @b3Extra = "&nbsp;"
IF @artistEventCount > 1 THEN
SET @b3Extra = Concat('<span valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans serif; color:#333333; font-size:16px; line-height:16px;font-weight:400;padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;" class="opensans centerText paddingLR20">', @eventDates ,'</span><br>')
ENDIF
IF @artistEventCount > 1 THEN
SET @b3Extra = Concat(@b3Extra, '<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#e41937; text-transform:uppercase;" href="', @ymal_event_url, '" alias="event', @artistCount,'">See More Dates</a>')
ENDIF
]%%
%%=ContentAreaByName("Shared Items\Shared Contents\DevModule\NewsletterB3Dev")=%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```